# Magento 2.3.5 script to change attribute set groups name

Tags: magento2.3, attribute-set, script

We have a lot of attribute sets in our store 100+. And by default the general group name inside a attribute set is called "Product Details" we want to change/translate this text.

We already tried this by adding it into the i18n file, but that does not seem to work.

So now I am looking for a script to change the group name of the "Product Details" into a new phrase.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mysql directly, you can use the query below:

```
update eav_attribute_group set attribute_group_name='My new name' where attribute_group_code='product-details';
```

once you will have run the query, My new name will be the group name instead of Product Details.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect.